# Including any file to your main executable

Tags: c++

Im searching a way to store a file (or multiple files) in my main executable. Let suppose I have a program called ***example.exe***, What I want to do is include another file inside of that program, let call it ***foo.exe***, Well I need to execute the ***foo.exe*** file without needing to launch it dynamically (With commands like *System* or *ShellExecute*), To be more accurate, only having ONE file in the running directory, Also serve that the ***foo.exe*** file is copied temporaly to the running directory (Probably invisible) or a temp directory like %LOCALAPPDATA%, Run it(With *Shell* or *ShellExecute*), Then when finished the operation, Delete the file. Thanks in advance.

**example.exe // example.cpp**

```
#include <windows.h>
//What I need to include?

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE Inst, HINSTANCE PrevInst,
LPSTR CmdLine, int CmdShow)
{
    //What I need to do here?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This can't be done entirely in code.  To link arbitrary things into the executable, you have to tell the _linker_ to do that, and the linker doesn't read your code.  How are you building this project, Visual Studio I assume?

Comment: Yes, Im using Visual Studio.

Comment: You can load an EXE with LoadLibrary as if it's a DLL, I've always wondered if it's useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible, but it's difficult.

First, you need compile your `foo` project and get `foo.exe`.

In the `example` project you should create files **resource.h** and **resource.rc**:

**resource.h**

```
#define FOO_RESOURCE 1000
```

**resource.rc**

```
#include "resource.h"
FOO_RESOURCE RCDATA "path to foo.exe"
```

Second, in **example.cpp** you should load the binary data and store into a file:

```
#include "resource.h"

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR sCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    HRSRC hRSrc = ::FindResource(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(FOO_RESOURCE), RT_RCDATA);

    HGLOBAL hResource = ::LoadResource(NULL, hRSrc);
    unsigned char* data = (unsigned char*)::LockResource(hResource);
    DWORD size = ::SizeofResource(NULL, hRSrc);

    // Store size bytes of data to "foo.exe"
    _TCHAR filename[MAX_PATH];
    ::GetEnvironmentVariable(_T("LOCALAPPDATA"), filename, MAX_PATH);
    size_t filenameLength = _tcslen(filename);
    if (filename[filenameLength - 1] == _T('\\'))
        _tcscat(filename, _T("foo.exe"));
    else
        _tcscat(filename, _T("\\foo.exe"));

    HANDLE hFile = ::CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

    DWORD written;
    ::WriteFile(hFile, data, size, &written, NULL);
    ::CloseHandle(hFile);
    ::ShellExecute(NULL, _T("open"), filename, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);

    // You don't need to unlock resources
}
```

At least, you need compile .rc file by resource compiler (rc.exe). It gives .res file.
This .res file you should link into **example.exe**.

VS can simplify the process. Just try to add a resource to the `example` project.

Comment: Ok, that link the file inside the application, but now, which command I should use to run **foo.exe**?

Comment: You can use any method you like. In low-level Win API it can be `::CreateProcess`, but you can also use `::ShellExecute`, or even good old `system` function.

Comment: I tried to use ShellExecute, but when I fill the parameters, a syntax error is thrown:
Argument of type "unsigned char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR".
Here what I writted:
`ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, data, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);`

Comment: @dylamsamuel `LPCWSTR` is the same as `const wchar_t *`. You need to use a wide string.

Comment: First, you need store data to file using `::CreateFile` and `::WriteFile`. Best place to locate a file is `%LOCALAPPDATA%` (this is an environment variable). Do you need full source code?

Comment: @dylamsamuel sorry, that wide string I spoke of earlier is a *file name*. You need to take Mark Shevchenko's advice and write the data to a file first.

Comment: @dylamsamuel I've updated the code, but I didn't compile it, so there may be syntax errors.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko I included the header _TCHAR.h_ and checked the syntax, the programs runs normally, but I doesn't create the file **foo.exe**, I tested other locations (both absolute and relative paths), I also tested the application with administrator priveleges without success... I think that the problem is WriteFile, but I honestly don't know...

Comment: I dropped all checks for errors in the code. If the file is not created, then most likely `::CreateFile` function returns `NULL`. Try to run the code in the debugger step-by-step. If `hFile` will be equals to `NULL`, call `::GetLastError` after `::CreateFile` and google for error code. Check filename before `::CreateFile`, it may be invalid, f.e. because there is not the `LOCALAPPDATA` environment variable at your machine.

Comment: I debugged the program as suggested, WriteFile returned NULL, after that I got that CloseHandle returned NULL too... As I sais before, I tested administrator priveleges and possible paths without success..

Comment: Before WriteFile what are values of hFile, data, and size?

Comment: I retrieved some information: The error given by _WriteFile_ is 126; and the variable _size_ number is 6041088.

Comment: Something is going wrong here, because the file size of **foo.exe** is 11.776 bytes, and 6.041.088 bytes is extremaly bigger, I think that is a Access Violation... But why _size_ retrieve that amount?

Comment: 126 means "invalid module". It seems that nor LoadResource or SizeofResource are the reason of error.

Comment: functions _LoadResource_ and _SizeofResource_ first argument is a Module Handle, it is NULL in the example writed above, but I tested with _GetModuleHandle(NULL)_ and _hInstance_, No one works...

Comment: Wait a hour, I'll try to test it.

Comment: Use `_T("foo.exe")`/`_T("\\foo.exe")` instead of `"foo.exe"` and "\\foo.exe". Insert `written` variable and pass it as a parameter to `WriteFile`. I've updated my answer, so you can look the code.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I finally solved the problem, I will accept this question as correct!. By the way, I created a function so people can use it more easily: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=kZpN9qhV
You should link that paste on the answer for the people who are searching solutions...

Answer (score 1):

Three common solutions (widely documented on the Internet):

- Windows resources (easy to create with Visual Studio, some API calls necessary to retrieve the data);
- use a tool like `xxd` to automatically generate (perhaps as a pre-build step) a cpp containing your exe stored in an array. Using it from the main program then is trivial:
- append your data to the executable (typically as a pre-build step), along with its size. To extract it you have to go at the end of the file (maybe exploiting the fact that it is already mapped in memory), read the size, go back accordingly and *voilà* there's your data.

Comment: The API calls are [FindResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [LoadResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046(v=vs.85).aspx), but I couldn't find an easy tutorial on how to add random binary files :/

Comment: @MooingDuck: last time I used the VS resource editor you could easily add arbitrary binary data (that would be the `RCDATA` directive in the generated resource script); IIRC it was the default for any file you added that wasn't recognized as matching particular resource types.

Comment: You can, for example, Add all the files to a resource file and then link the resource.rc to the application? Then just simply use _MAKEINTRESOURCE_ or something like that?

Comment: Wops, memory slip; RCDATA was for *inline* binary data, to include files you have to use *user defined* resource types (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381054(v=vs.85).aspx.

Comment: By the way, I googled **xdd**, and random things appeared, what do you mean with **xdd**?

Comment: Positive for the first question; as for xxd, I mean [this](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/xxd1.html) with option `-i`.

Comment: I tested my first teory of including a resource file with the path of the **foo.exe**, It linked the file to the application (the weight of **example.exe** aumented according to **foo.exe** weight) but now I don't know how to access it...

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project, select "Add", then "Resource...".  For the dialog that pops up, select "Import...", and select your file.  This includes your binary file in your executable.

Now, in your code, you include `"Windows.h"`, and use [`FindResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a handle to the data, and then [`LoadResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046(v=vs.85).aspx) to load the file into memory and get a pointer to it.  You'll also need [`SizeofResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648048(v=vs.85).aspx) to determine the full size. You can then do whatever you want with that.  Don't forget to free the handles when you're done!  Vague samples are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648008%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Given your goal, I think your next step would be to copy this binary file to a temporary executable file, execute it, then delete it.  I assume that your question was more about the embedding and loading rather than the subsequent steps, so I'll stop here.